# Are marriage and death predestined?

Tags: marriage, death, future

If yes then how people used to marry more than once in previous ages and now they only marry once as per the law.
Does it mean that death and marriage are not predestined?

Comment: Death..Lifespan is predetermined. Can't say about marriage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes . Both marriage and death is predestined . When we talk about the life of Rama , he married to Ma Sita which was predestined . When we talk about Lord Shiva , he was predestined to marry Ma Parvati who sacrificed her life in the Agni in her previous birth .
When we talk about death , we can take the example of Lord Krishna who died by a simpler hunter .